# SELECT query on multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables,

```
ID  NAME
-------------------
12  Jon Doe
4   Jane Doe
9   Sam Doe
```

AND

```
MemID   Cat#            DateChkOut      DateDue          DateRet
4   T 430.98 1956      15-Mar-2011      14-Jun-2011     31-May-2011
12  B 125.2 2013       15-Mar-2011      14-Jun-2011 
4   T 430.98 1956      27-Dec-2012      25-Mar-2013
```

Now I need to list the `members’ names who have never checked out a book.

`SELECT Name FROM MEMBER, CHECKOUT WHERE ID != MemID;`

did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: so all records of users who do not have any entry in the 2nd table thats it ?

Comment: What to do with persons how never had a book?

Comment: Yes, the left join got me what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` in this case.

Try the following:

```
SELECT M.Name
FROM MembersTable M
LEFT JOIN CheckoutTable C On C.MemId = M.ID
WHERE C.MemId IS NULL
```

Edit:

`LEFT JOIN` works in this situation because it joins the two tables on a common key - in this case the `MemId`.  Since this is a `LEFT JOIN` it will take everything that exists in the Left table (Members) and if a match is found, it will include everything on the Right table (Checkout).  But if no match is found in the Checkout table, everything on that side will be `NULL`.

So, all you would need to do is check to see if the Right side is `NULL`.

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: It works! Could you explain how it works? Why is there a "WHERE C.MemId IS NULL" if we are already checking "C.MemId = M.ID"

Comment: I understand it now. was being dumb. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name FROM member WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MemID FROM checkout)
```

I think it should do the job

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,
       name
FROM Member
WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT memid
     FROM checkout)
```

or

```
SELECT id,
       name
FROM member m
LEFT OUTER JOIN checkout c ON m.id = c.memid
WHERE c.memid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery with NOT EXISTS.

```
SELECT Name 
  FROM MEMBER a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CHECKOUT b WHERE b.MemID = a.ID)
```

See [Optimizing Subqueries with EXISTS Strategy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `NOT IN` in the query, that can be slow for large queries, try instead following using `JOIN`, which will be way faster:

```
SELECT MEMBER.NAME FROM MEMBER 
LEFT JOIN CHECKOUT ON CHECKOUT.MemID = MEMBER.ID 
WHERE CHECKOUT.MemID IS NULL:
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you may want more fields returned an outer join is good method of accomplishing this.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM MEMBER M
LEFT JOIN CHECKOUT C
 on M.ID = C.MemID
WHERE C.MemID is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT M.ID,M.Name 
FROM MEMBER M LEFT JOIN
     CHECKOUT C ON C.MemID=M.ID
WHERE C.DateRet IS NULL
```

It will select the user details whose `DateRet` is null.

Sample result:

```
ID  NAME
-------------------
12  Jon Doe
4   Jane Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `where in` and check for the `DateChkOut`:

```
SELECT Name
FROM   MEMBER
WHERE  ID not in
       ( select MemID
         from   CHECKOUT
         where  DateChkOut is not null
       )
```